# Modification of agg function to show values using descending Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I modyfy below code so as to present for instance "mean" by descending so from the biggest to the lowest amount ?

```
data.groupby(["Duration"]).agg({'Credit amount':[min, max, np.mean, np.median, sum]})
```

currently my output is:
[image]

And I would like to sort it by descending it terms of for example mean. So I would like to have sorted this table based on mean column from the biggest to the lowest

Comment: please add a sample input and expected output of your data

Comment: you can use `.sort_values()` but in the absence of a reproducable answer we can't test. please provide your sample input and output as text and read [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify what is the column index you want to sort. After an aggregation, the columns' indexes are usually tuples. If it is the "mean" values, then the index is `('Credit amount', 'mean')`.

```
columns_to_sort = [('Credit amount', 'mean')]

table = data.groupby(["Duration"]).agg({'Credit amount':[min, max, np.mean, np.median, sum]})

sorted_table = table.sort_values(by=columns_to_sort, ascending=False)
```

You will have your data sorted on the `sorted_table` variable.

---

You can also find all the columns' indexes by checking `table.columns`